# Keycloak as subresource behind Apache2

Tags: proxy, webserver, apache2, keycloak

Keycloak is running on Docker image jboss/keycloak and environment variable       PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING is set to true. I would like to setup Keycloak behind Apache2 webserver as subresource. When I my Apache configuration is:

```
ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8080/
ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:8080/
```

I have access to KeyCloak, however I'm loosing access to another resources on the server, for example /panel or /wordpress. I've tried to do the following:

```
ProxyPass /keycloak/ http://127.0.0.1:8080/
ProxyPassReverse /keycloak/ http://127.0.0.1:8080/
```

But with above configuration I'm redirected to /auth on a server instead of Keycloak's auth.

Could you help me to configure Keycloak as a subresource on Apache2 webserver?

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to make it work. I created the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM jboss/keycloak
RUN sed -i -e 's/<web-context>auth<\/web-context>/<web-context>keycloak\/auth<\/web-context>/' $JBOSS_HOME/standalone/configuration/standalone-ha.xml
```

after rebuilding an image I've changed my Apache2 configuration as follows:

```
ProxyPass /keycloak/ http://127.0.0.1:8080/keycloak/
ProxyPassReverse /keycloak/ http://127.0.0.1:8080/keycloak/
```

Now KeyCloak works from the same domain as a subresource.